# How to change the text of a button to the data of a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am making an app in Xcode 5 and I am stuck because I want to change the text of my button (`Answer1`) to the text of my `NSString` (`OAnswer1`) here is what I got off the internet:
Following is my code :

```
[Answer1 setTitle:@"Text goes here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

when i change it to

```
[Answer1 setTitle:@"%@", OAnswer1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

it has errors,

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or simply (if you know `OAnswer1` is a string)

```
[Answer1 setTitle:OAnswer1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and you really shouldn't have capitalized variable names...

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a `NSString` object in `setTitle` parameter.

```
[Answer1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",OAnswer1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Apple developer link for further study:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:

**EDIT:**
 i guess user wants to set some custom combination of string so i used `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`

Comment: Using `stringWithFormat` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Martin R I agree with you,Here no need to use "[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@",OAnswer1]", just have to use 'OAnswer1'

Comment: U can see my `EDIT:`. Reason why i've used it. @DivyaBhalodiya

Comment: Here user is very straight forward about its Query and he clearly said "OAnswer1" is NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this:

```
NSString *strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",OAnswer1];

[Answer1 setTitle:strTemp forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thank you user1505866 you really helped, I will except your answer in 11 minutes!

Comment: Using `stringWithFormat` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: yeah, you can directly put OAnswer1 instead of @"%@".